# SelectBox getID

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to get the id of a selection of a select box, however was unable'm confused, can someone help me?

Code of Selectbox:

**Edited SelectBox Code :**

```
 <li class="fields">
                <div>
                    <div class="field">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="required" for="type_id"><?php echo $this->__('Occasion') ?><em>*</em></label>
                            <div class="input-box">
                                <select id="type_id" name="type_id" title="<?php echo $this->__('Occasion') ?>" class="validate-select form-control" onChange="criaDados(), showId(<?php $this->getId() ?>)" <?php if (!is_null ($_e->getId())) { echo "style='display: none;'"; } ?> >

                                   <option value=""><?php echo $this->__('Please select occasion') ?></option>
                                   <?php foreach($_e->getTypes() as $k=>$v):?>
                                    <option value="<?php echo $k ?>" <?php if($_e->getTypeId() == $k) echo 'selected'?>><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($v) ?></option>
                                   <?php endforeach; ?>
                                </select>

                                <input type="text" value="<?php echo $_e->getTypes()[$_e->getTypeId()] ?>"  class="form-control" disabled <?php if (is_null ($_e->getId())) { echo "style='display: none;'"; } ?> />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="field">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="required" for="date"><?php echo $this->__('Date') ?><em>*</em></label>
                            <div class="input-box">
                                <div class="input-range input-date">
                                    <?php echo $this->getDateInput($_e->getDate()) ?>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
```

**Edited Javascript**

```
 function showId(id)
    {
        var id_val = $("#" + id).val();
        alert(id_val);
    }
```

Comment: if you need value of selected box you can replace showId(<?php $this->getId() ?>)"  with  showId(this.value)

Comment: you have syntax error here value="<?php echo $_e->getTypes()[$_e->getTypeId()] ?>"   in the input tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to get the id of the selected item then add an `onchange` event in select 
like `onchange="showid(this)"`

then javascript

```
function showid(ids) {
      console.log(ids[ids.selectedIndex].value); // get value
      console.log(ids[ids.selectedIndex].id); // get id
    }
```

if you want jquery solution then do  something like below

```
$('#type_id').change(function(){
   alert($(this).find('option:selected').attr('id'));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can replace content in function parameter with this.id like below

```
<div class="field">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="required" for="type_id"><?php echo $this->__('Occasion') ?><em>*</em></label>
        <div class="input-box">
            <select id="type_id" name="type_id" title="<?php echo $this->__('Occasion') ?>" class="validate-select form-control" onChange="criaDados(), showId('this.id') { echo "style='display: none;'"; } ?> >
               <option value=""><?php echo $this->__('Please select occasion') ?></option>
               <?php foreach($_e->getTypes() as $k=>$v):?>
                <option value="<?php echo $k ?>" <?php if($_e->getTypeId() == $k) echo 'selected'?>><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($v) ?></option>
               <?php endforeach; ?>
            </select>  
            <input type="text" value="<?php echo $_e->getTypes()[$_e->getTypeId()] ?>"  class="form-control" disabled <?php if (is_null ($_e->getId())) { echo "style='display: none;'"; } ?> />
        </div>
    </div>                              
</div>
```

Then you can use it

```
function showId(id)
{
   var id_val = $("#" + id).val();
   alert(id_val);
}
```

Comment: hello, can not run the event and see the id in my Alert ()
put the edited code up there!

Comment: @HelderRocha You can not call two function on one event at a time but what you can do is you can call the second function from inside the first one if you want

Answer (score 0):

not sure what you mean by 'get' but I'm guessing JavaScript

```
document.getElementById('type-id');
showId(document.getElementById('type-id'));
```

Answer (score -1):

I see you use Bootstrap, so jQuery is not far away.
How about this:

```
function showId(id){
var v = $("#" + id).val();
alert(v);
}
```

or something like this:

```
$( "#"+id+" option:selected" ).text();
```

Second one gets the selected text, the other one the selected value of the selected option.

Comment: i think the questioner is trying to find the  id of the selected item. correct me if i am wrong , if am i right then how he get the id from your code ?

Comment: i did not down voting , but with curiosity can i ask why no more answering ?